# Ruby - Permutations, lack of outputs

Tags: ruby

```
def permutations(str)
  str.split(//).permutation.with_index.to_a.delete_if{|x,i| x[i].eql? x[i+1]}.flatten(1).to_a.delete_if{|x| x.class == Integer}.map{|x| x.join}
end
```

Desc:
"In this kata you have to create all permutations of an input string and remove duplicates, if present. This means, you have to shuffle all letters from the input in all possible orders."

Expected Input / Output:

```
permutations('aabb') # => ['aabb', 'abab', 'abba', 'baab', 'baba', 'bbaa']
```

My Input/ Output:

```
permutations('aabb') # =>  ["aabb", "abab", "abba"]
```

So there is a problem with:

```
'baab', 'baba', 'bbaa'
```

Have You got any ideas? I'm sorry if my code doesn't look clear but can I set this kind of methods like this? :

```
str.split(//)
   .to_a
   .delete_if 
   .etc
```

I'm not sure but in my opinion it's problem with this part of code but I can't figure it out:

```
.delete_if{|x,i| x[i] == x[i+1]}
```

Comment: Try `str.chars.permutation.map(&:join).uniq`.

Comment: I always forget about this shortcut `(&:join)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When faced with a problem like this, it is often a good idea to

- break the code apart into smaller, simpler pieces
- write lots and lots and lots of tests encoding all of your assumptions what you think the code is doing
- trace the execution of the code with pen and paper
- single-step the code in a debugger, comparing it to the results you get from the pen and paper debugging

I'll focus mostly on #1 and #3 here. Let's first reformat the code a bit to make it easier to read:

```ruby
str.
  split(//).
  permutation.
  with_index.
  to_a.
  delete_if { |x, i| x[i].eql? x[i + 1] }.
  flatten(1).
  to_a.
  delete_if { |x| x.class == Integer }.
  map { |x| x.join }
```

Now, let's break the code apart, assigning an intention revealing name to each individual part. The first thing we do is to [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split) the [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) apart at the empty string, in other words, we are separating it into single characters. So, let's call this `characters` (This is basically just a re-implementation of the already existing method [`String#chars`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-each_char):

```ruby
characters = str.split(//)
#=> ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
```

In the next step, we are generating all permutations of this character array:

```ruby
permutations = characters.permutation
```

This returns us an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html), which we then convert to an [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html):

```ruby
permutations_array = permutations.to_a
#=> [["a", "a", "b", "b"],
#    ["a", "a", "b", "b"],
#    ["a", "b", "a", "b"],
#    ["a", "b", "b", "a"],
#    ["a", "b", "a", "b"],
#    ["a", "b", "b", "a"],
#    ["a", "a", "b", "b"],
#    ["a", "a", "b", "b"],
#    ["a", "b", "a", "b"],
#    ["a", "b", "b", "a"],
#    ["a", "b", "a", "b"],
#    ["a", "b", "b", "a"],
#    ["b", "a", "a", "b"],
#    ["b", "a", "b", "a"],
#    ["b", "a", "a", "b"],
#    ["b", "a", "b", "a"],
#    ["b", "b", "a", "a"],
#    ["b", "b", "a", "a"],
#    ["b", "a", "a", "b"],
#    ["b", "a", "b", "a"],
#    ["b", "a", "a", "b"],
#    ["b", "a", "b", "a"],
#    ["b", "b", "a", "a"],
#    ["b", "b", "a", "a"]]
```

Now we pair up every permutation with its index:

```ruby
permutations_with_index = permutations_array.with_index
```

This will again return us an `Enumerator`, which we convert to an `Array`:

```ruby
permutations_with_index_array = permutations_with_index.to_a
#=> [[["a", "a", "b", "b"], 0],
#    [["a", "a", "b", "b"], 1],
#    [["a", "b", "a", "b"], 2],
#    [["a", "b", "b", "a"], 3],
#    [["a", "b", "a", "b"], 4],
#    [["a", "b", "b", "a"], 5],
#    [["a", "a", "b", "b"], 6],
#    [["a", "a", "b", "b"], 7],
#    [["a", "b", "a", "b"], 8],
#    [["a", "b", "b", "a"], 9],
#    [["a", "b", "a", "b"], 10],
#    [["a", "b", "b", "a"], 11],
#    [["b", "a", "a", "b"], 12],
#    [["b", "a", "b", "a"], 13],
#    [["b", "a", "a", "b"], 14],
#    [["b", "a", "b", "a"], 15],
#    [["b", "b", "a", "a"], 16],
#    [["b", "b", "a", "a"], 17],
#    [["b", "a", "a", "b"], 18],
#    [["b", "a", "b", "a"], 19],
#    [["b", "a", "a", "b"], 20],
#    [["b", "a", "b", "a"], 21],
#    [["b", "b", "a", "a"], 22],
#    [["b", "b", "a", "a"], 23]]
```

The next step is where it gets interesting.

There is some sort of filtering going on. But it is not yet clear what exactly that filtering is doing. So, we follow the same steps we followed above: we break everything down into small pieces and examine each piece individually:

```ruby
mystery = permutations_with_index_array.delete_if do |mystery1, mystery2| 
  mystery3 = mystery1[mystery2]
  mystery4 = mystery1[mystery2 + 1]
  mystery5 = mystery3.eql?(mystery4)
end
```

So, let's look at what the pieces are. [`Array#delete_if`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) `yield`s each element of the array to the block. So, the first element that is `yield`ed is `[["a", "a", "b", "b"], 0]`.

Because our block actually has two parameters, `mystery1` and `mystery2`, this element (which is itself an array) gets *destructured* into the first and second element, that means `mystery1` is the array of characters and `mystery2` is the index. So, we have already figured out our two first mysteries:

```ruby
mystery = permutations_with_index_array.delete_if do |character_array, index| 
  mystery3 = character_array[index]
  mystery4 = character_array[index + 1]
  mystery5 = mystery3.eql?(mystery4)
end
```

Now, let's take a closer look at `mystery3`, `mystery4`, and `mystery5`, and let's use a concrete example. Actually, since this is a loop, let's use three concrete examples: the first iteration, an iteration somewhere in the middle, and the last iteration.

In the first iteration, `character_array` is `['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']` and `index` is `0`. That means `mystery3` is the first element of `character_array`, `'a'`, and `mystery4` is the second element of `character_array`, also `'a'`.

And since `'a'` is equal to `'a'`, `mystery5` is `true`, that means the whole block is `true`, and that means, that this whole permutation is being discarded.

Now let's look at the *fifth* iteration. `character_array` is `['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']` and `index` is `4`. That means `mystery3` is the *fifth* element of `character_array`, *but there is no fifth element*! Requesting an array index that does not actually exist returns `nil`, thus `mystery3` is `nil`. And `mystery4` is the sixth element of `character_array`, which is also `nil`.

And since `nil` is equal to `nil`, `mystery5` is `true`, that means the whole block is `true`, and that means, that this whole permutation is being discarded. In fact, from this iteration on, *all* elements will be discarded, because `index` is only getting bigger and bigger. You will *never* get more than four permutations (in this example).

More generally, you will always get *at least one* permutation, namely the `str.length - 1`th one, because in the `str.length - 1`th iteration, `x[i]` will be a character and `x[i + 1]` will be `nil`, which are never equal. And you will get *at most* `str.length - 1` permutations, because starting with the `str.length`th iteration, both `x[i]` and `x[i + 1]` will always be `nil` and thus always be equal.

I'll stop going through the rest of the code here, because we can clearly see that we have found the problem and what the problem is: you are confusing the index of the array with all the permutations with the array that is a single permutation.

This would be easy to fix, but then we would run into a different problem: not only are you "doing it wrong", but even what you are trying to do is also wrong. You are trying to determine duplicates by *only* looking at the current and the next index. But, two things are still duplicates if they are not next to each other! That's really what [`Enumerable#uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-uniq) is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
def permutations(str)
  x = str.split(//).permutation.map(&:join).uniq
end
```

I found solution and there was a problem with:

```
.delete_if{|x,i| x[i] == x[i+1]}
```

I deleted it and added .uniq at the end of whole method.